# Debug Errors, site health

Tags: debug

When I go to site health this is what I am seeing.

```
Debug mode is often enabled to gather more details about an error or site failure, but may contain sensitive information which should not be available on a publicly available website.

The value, WP_DEBUG_LOG, has been added to this website’s configuration file. This means any errors on the site will be written to a file which is potentially available to normal users.
```

What should the file be?
I looked at https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ and I did not see what the file is support to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for the `wp-config.php` file in the root of your WordPress installation. From the documentation in the [WP_Debug Section](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug)

> `WP_DEBUG` is a PHP constant (a permanent global variable) that can be
>   used to trigger the “debug” mode throughout WordPress. It is assumed
>   to be false by default and is usually set to true in the
>   [wp-config.php](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) file on development copies of WordPress.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: It's likely a problem that requires developer intervention and not something easily fixable. If you don't see any issues with your website you can likely ignore the message. You would enable Debugging in your wp-config.php file as the examples [shows in the documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#example-wp-config-php-for-debugging). Browse around the website, and any PHP errors or notices will appear in a `wp-content/debug.log`

Comment: Okay thank you.